# Mostrar en un input la fecha seleccionada Date Picker - React Native

Tags: react-native

Tengo un datepicker del plugin npm i react-native-date-picker y funciona sin problemas pero necesito que al seleccionar la fecha me arroje la fecha que seleccione en campo input pero no lo he logado hacer.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Button } from 'react-native'
import DatePicker from 'react-native-date-picker'

export default () => {
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date())
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)

  return (
    <>
      <Button title="Open" onPress={() => setOpen(true)} />
      <DatePicker
        modal
        open={open}
        date={date}
        onConfirm={(date) => {
          setOpen(false)
          setDate(date)
        }}
        onCancel={() => {
          setOpen(false)
        }}
      />
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenía el mismo problema y lo revolví de la siguiente forma:

Al parecer no se puede mostrar un Date en JSX por lo tanto hice lo siguiente:

```
    <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.8} onPress={() => setOpen(true)}>
        <Text>Fecha</Text>
        <Text> {fechaFormato} </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>


    <DatePicker
      modal
      open={open}
      mode="date"
      date={date}
      onConfirm={date => {
        setOpen(false);
        formatFecha(date);
      }}
      onCancel={() => {
        setOpen(false);
      }}
    />
```

Al momento de querer guardar la fecha envié la misma hacia un método que la transforma en string y así la puedo mostrar.

```
 const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
 const [fechaFormato, setFechaFormato] = useState('');


 const formatFecha = fecha => {
    setDate(fecha);
    const dia = fecha.getDate();
    const mes = fecha.getMonth() + 1;
    const anio = fecha.getFullYear();
    setFechaFormato(`${dia}/${mes}/${anio}`);
  };
```